# Loop through values and display in a pdf file

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

i have written the following code:
As you can see there is a for loop to go through some values and display them in the generated pdf. The problem is that all the values are being written at the same place.
I have tried to insert a new line but it does not seem to work. Can anyone suggest me how i can do it? Do i need to write a nested  for loop so that it the values at different y positions?

```
$pdf = pdf_new();

            // open a file
            pdf_open_file($pdf, "C:/xampp/htdocs/final/6.pdf");
            pdf_set_info($pdf, "Author", "");
            pdf_set_info($pdf, "Title", "");
            pdf_set_info($pdf, "Creator", "");
            pdf_set_info($pdf, "Subject", "");
            // start a new page (A4)
            $x = 595;
            $y = 842;
            pdf_begin_page($pdf, $x, $y);
            pdf_set_parameter($pdf, 'FontOutline', 'Arial=c:\windows\fonts\arial.ttf');
            pdf_setcolor($pdf, "stroke", "rgb", 0, 0, 0, 1.0);

            // get and use a font object
            $font = pdf_findfont($pdf, "Arial", "host", 1);

            pdf_setfont($pdf, $font, 10);

            // print text
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "QUOTATION" , 250, $y - 60);
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Customer Name: " . $this->customer_details['first_name'] .
                " " . $this->customer_details['last_name'], 50, 770);
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Date: " . date("F j, Y, g:i a"), 50, 750);
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Number of items requested: " . $count_items_req, 50, 730);
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Number of items found: " . $count_items_found, 50, 710);


            // add an image under the text
            $image = $image = PDF_load_image($pdf, "png",
                "C:/xampp/htdocs/final/images/footer_logo.png", "");

            PDF_fit_image($pdf, $image, 50, 785, "");
            pdf_moveto($pdf, 20, 780);
            pdf_lineto($pdf, 575, 780);
            pdf_stroke($pdf);

            // draw another line near the bottom of the page
            pdf_moveto($pdf, 20, 50);
            pdf_lineto($pdf, 575, 50);
            pdf_stroke($pdf);

            //Draw the lines
            $offset = 184;
            $i = 0;
            pdf_moveto($pdf, 20, $y - 160);
            pdf_lineto($pdf, $x - 20, $y - 160);
            pdf_stroke($pdf);

            pdf_moveto($pdf, $x - 400, $y - 160);
            pdf_lineto($pdf, $x - 400, 80);
            pdf_stroke($pdf);

            pdf_moveto($pdf, $x - 200, $y - 160);
            pdf_lineto($pdf, $x - 200, 80);
            pdf_stroke($pdf);

            pdf_moveto($pdf, $x - 100, $y - 160);
            pdf_lineto($pdf, $x - 100, 80);
            pdf_stroke($pdf);

            pdf_continue_text($pdf, '');
            pdf_continue_text($pdf, '');

            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Searched Item", 70, $y - 150);
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Searched Item", 70, $y - 150);


            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Item name", 240, $y - 150);
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Item name", 240, $y - 150);
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Price", $x - 180, $y - 150);
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Price", $x - 180, $y - 150);
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Discounted Price", $x - 100, $y - 150);
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "Discounted Price", $x - 100, $y - 150);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->quotation_details); $i++)
            {

                 pdf_show_xy($pdf, $this->quotation_details[$i]['name_searched'] , 70, $y - 500);

            }


            // and write some text under it
            pdf_show_xy($pdf, "", 250, 35);


            // end page
            pdf_end_page($pdf);

            // close and save file
            pdf_close($pdf);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop, you just need to change the value you subtract from $y each time. You can do it like so:

```
$placeholder = 500; // initial value
for ($i = 0; $i quotation_details); $i++)
{
  pdf_show_xy($pdf, $this->quotation_details[$i]['name_searched'] , 70, $y - $placeholder);
  $placeholder = $placeholder - 20;
}
```

You might want to subtract by more or less than 20. Play around and find a value that looks good.